# how to get the result of an array with its respective key?

Tags: php, arrays

*I eliminated another question where I explained everything wrong, I hope this is more specific*

**I saw similar questions but this case is something particular**

I need that for each value of the array that I give, return the result with its respective key ([264], [265], etc).

i have this array:

```
array(2) {
  [264]=>
  string(38) "64,74,103,102,101,100,23,13,3,89,88,87"     //the value that I need to pass as a parameter
  [265]=>
  string(29) "65,95,96,97,83,84,88,62,54,44"             //the value that I need to pass as a parameter
}
```

my function:

```
function ArrayData($id){

  foreach($id as $singleId){

    $Data[][key($id)] = getData($singleId);  //here I pass the value as parameter

  }


}

/**
 * get the result data
 *
 * @return {array} $id
 */
function getData($singleId){
  $result = fetchData($singleId);             //here i get the result of the value
  $decode = json_decode($result, true);

  return $decode;
}
```

result of my function:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [264]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "64"
        ["concepto"]=>
        string(27) "IIBB Contribuyentes Locales"
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(10) "Anticipo10"
        ["agencia"]=>
        string(4) "ARBA"
        ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
        string(10) "2017-11-21"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [264]=>                   //[this has to be 265]
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "65"
        ["concepto"]=>
        string(27) "IIBB Contribuyentes Locales"
        ["impuesto"]=>
        string(10) "Anticipo10"
        ["agencia"]=>
        string(4) "ARBA"
        ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
        string(10) "2017-11-22"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the array shows both results with the same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty confusing, but I think you want this:

```
function ArrayData($id){

  foreach($id as $key=>$singleId){

    $Data[][$key] = getData($singleId);  //here I pass the value as parameter

  }


}
```